# HTML5 Canvas Game- Disappearing Elements

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm toying with simple game creation using the canvas, and I've created a simple setup on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wewogusopa/1/edit?js,output).  It uses the arrow keys to move the player around and collect gold that respawns thereafter.  Everything works great.

EXCEPT.  When I initially run the code, the player and gold squares flash on the canvas, then disappear.  They will only reappear after all four arrow keys have been pressed in turn.  I have determined that the issue is in my update function where I'm checking the down variables, but I'm not sure what I should be doing differently.  I welcome your insight and wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to declare the `leftDown,upDown,downDown,rightDown` variables so your update() fails when trying to use `rightdown`

Fix: declare those variables:

```
var leftDown,upDown,downDown,rightDown;
```

Comment: You're welcome! Hint for the future: Check out the built-in development tools on your browser by pressing F12.  In particular, the Console tab will often point out the silly mistakes we all make. Good luck with your game! ;-)